# Can we append a text file with punctuations in ahk?

Tags: append, autohotkey, txt, punctuation

I am trying to append a txt file with punctuations to text to a file in AHK but it seems to break the line even if i use round brackets. How can I append to a file without breaking it?

```
                FileAppend, ({
                                "accounts": [
                                    {
                                        "active": true,
                                        "type": "dummy",
                                        "ygg": {
                                            "extra": {
                                                "clientToken": "123456789",
                                                "userName": "BX0W"
                                            },
                                            "iat": 1655273051,
                                            "token": "BX0W"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "formatVersion": 3
                    }), accounts.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Even inside a function my experience with a [continuation section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation) is that the parentheses must be the beginning of each line (with no preceding whitespaces) for it to work. I am guessing that it has something to do with the compiler.

```
    FileAppend, 
(
                    {
                                "accounts": [
                                    {
                                        "active": true,
                                        "type": "dummy",
                                        "ygg": {
                                            "extra": {
                                                "clientToken": "123456789",
                                                "userName": "BX0W"
                                            },
                                            "iat": 1655273051,
                                            "token": "BX0W"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "formatVersion": 3
                    }
), accounts.json
```